# Can I freeze rolled out pie dough

Tags: baking, storage-method, dough

A typical pie dough recipe ([such as this one](https://www.kingarthurflour.com/recipes/classic-double-pie-crust-recipe)) asks to:

1. Mix the dough.
2. Make a couple thick disks.
3. Put the thick disks in the fridge 30 minutes to couple months in the freezer.
4. Remove thick disks, let them warm up a little, and roll them out.
5. Place them in the greased pan and put them back in the fridge for about half an hour.

My question: is there any reason I can't store my dough, pre-rolled out, in the freezer after step 4. Also, assuming the dough is just warmed enough to be able to put it in the pan would doing so still give the benefits of step 5?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure you can freeze rolled out pastry, it can be a real time-saver. The trick is to make sure it's protected from freezer burn, otherwise it can dry out. Putting it between two sheets of wax paper works well, then rolling it up and putting it in a freezer bag. You need to let it thaw before unrolling it otherwise it will break up and you'll have to roll it back out again.

Comment: I thought it would be a time saver :-)